# How do I stop xterm from sending backspace when I select "Ctrl+h"

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm, stty

I want xterm to stop converting Ctrl+h to backspace. I use this key combination for other things, but the terminal captures Ctrl+h and send backspace every time. How can I disable this?

Note this is not the same as other posts of disabling Backspace from sending Ctrl+h, I am dealing with the opposite.

Note: using Ubuntu 22.04 if it matters.

Comment: In your Xresource settings does adding `XTerm*VT100.Translations: Control-h: ignore` work?

Comment: "Backspace" is "Ctrl-H", read `man ascii`. You can select a different key to represent backspace, see `man stty`.

Comment: I assume CTRL-V then CTRL-H does not work? Not exactly what you are looking for, but...

Answer (score -1):

There are two different widespread behaviors in terminals for the Backspace key. One is to generate the byte 0x08 (a.k.a. ASCII `BS` or `backspace`, usually denoted as `^H`). The other is to generate the byte 0x7F (a.k.a. `DEL` or `delete`, usually denoted as `^?`).

I'm afraid there's still no general consensus which one to go for. My *impression* is that `^?` is the more typical. In fact, this is the choice where you do have a chance to distinguish the Backspace keypress from the Ctrl+H keypress. With the other choice they are necessarily the same. So, since your very goal is to differentiate these two, you should cast your vote for `^?`.

On Ubuntu, that's the default behavior I get in `xterm`. Upstream `xterm` and `terminfo` seems to default to `^H`, but Debian (and thus Ubuntu too) has a patch that modifies it to `^?`. I'm not sure why you see the `^H` behavior (if you do at all), maybe you have installed `xterm` manually for yourself. Or maybe your xterm generates `^?`, but the application that you use decides to perform the same action as for `^H`.

There are three main components that have to be set consistently with each other.

One is the actual behavior of your terminal emulator. To verify this, run the command `showkey -a` and then press Backspace. If it reports `^H` then you should change the terminal's behavior to emit `^?`.

The other is the line discipline settings, used by the kernel when the line is in cooked mode (e.g. when you run `cat` and expect the Backspace key to work as usual, rather than printing `^H` or `^?`). You can query the value with `stty -a` and looking for `erase = ...`, or set by `stty erase '^?'` or `stty erase '^H'`.

The third is the terminfo definition. Run `infocmp | grep kbs`, the value of `kbs` should be `^?` or `^H` matching all the rest (i.e. `^?`, that's what we're going for). If it's not the case, you should dig into terminfo to study how to alter its definition, or how to pick a different value for TERM. I don't know what consequences it has if it's not set correctly; I assume that text input fields in ncurses apps might work incorrectly on a Backspace keypress.

In what order should you set the above three? There's no obvious answer here. There are multiple valid solutions. You can set the terminal emulator to a certain behavior, maybe some terminals even automatically set the `stty` property to match. Or you can set the `stty` property first, and configure your terminal to behave like `stty` tells it to. You can also configure your `xterm` to behave according to the behavior described in terminfo. As for `xterm`, see `backarrowKeyIsErase` in its manual page to study the possibilities and pick one to go with. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the very exact details to tell you what to do exactly; mostly because on Ubuntu I got a consistent `^?` behavior by default so I didn't have to tamper with these.

Once you manage to configure these three places consistently to use `^?` (recap: 1. the terminal's actual behavior as verified by `showkey -a`, 2. the `stty` setting, and 3. terminfo's description of the current `$TERM` as verified by `infocmp`), the vast majority of applications should behave correctly, and should be able to distinguish Ctrl+H (byte 0x08) from the Backspace key (byte 0x7F). If it's still not the case in a particular application then you need to study the documentation and settings of that particular application.

If you `ssh` to a remote host, you should make sure that the `stty` settings are still correct after logging in, and that the remote terminfo database is also consistent with the actual behavior.